# Find data gaps and split in more tracks

Tags: r, split, gaps-in-data

I have tracking data for some animals and I want to know if I have tracks with more than 1 day gaps in the satellite transmission for each id.

And, if any, I need to split the tracks into 2 or more sub-tracks for the same id. So, some individuals will have more then one burst.

My data is like this (dput):

```
structure(list(id = c("20162.03", "20162.03", "20162.03", "20162.03", 
"20162.03", "20162.03", "20162.03", "20162.03", "20162.03", "20162.03", 
"20162.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", 
"20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "20687.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", 
"21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03", "21791.03"), date = structure(c(1066573980, 
1066738740, 1066743180, 1066754280, 1066762200, 1066905180, 1066931520, 
1067760840, 1067765760, 1067767740, 1067782200, 1067274120, 1067283840, 
1067288700, 1067292840, 1067294460, 1067306160, 1067307660, 1067315100, 
1067323920, 1067333160, 1067334780, 1067340240, 1067342160, 1067346360, 
1067348100, 1067384580, 1067385060, 1067391060, 1067393220, 1067400660, 
1067406780, 1067413740, 1067414580, 1067418900, 1067419860, 1067425380, 
1067431140, 1067433660, 1067445780, 1067452080, 1067459640, 1067478840, 
1067486460, 1067492460, 1067493780, 1067498760, 1067499780, 1067504700, 
1067510400, 1067516160, 1067519160, 1067522280, 1067531520, 1067537640, 
1067549640, 1067549820, 1067561160, 1067564460, 1067567280, 1067570340, 
1067572200, 1067578440, 1067584680, 1067589780, 1067590260, 1067596320, 
1067601180, 1067604900, 1067607300, 1067617140, 1067623440, 1067623440, 
1067629440, 1067634660, 1067640600, 1067646360, 1067650020, 1067652180, 
1067657940, 1067663820, 1067669700, 1067674680, 1067676180, 1067680560, 
1067682000, 1067686440, 1067690280, 1067692440, 1067696340, 1067702940, 
1067709120, 1067714700, 1067719560, 1067720400, 1067721120, 1067725620, 
1067727060, 1067731140, 1067735520, 1067737140, 1067741580, 1067743560, 
1067749620, 1067759880, 1067760720, 1067761620, 1067765640, 1067767560, 
1067775960, 1067781600, 1067788620, 1067795040, 1067804520, 1067805180, 
1067806740, 1067810460, 1067812800, 1067822280, 1067827140, 1067829360, 
1067835480, 1067845620, 1067850720, 1067853480, 1067861400, 1067862540, 
1067867580, 1067874420, 1067880660, 1067884320, 1067895480, 1067898420, 
1067906460, 1067907360, 1067915100, 1067921040, 1067930520, 1067935620, 
1067938800, 1067944800, 1067946960, 1067947500, 1067953080, 1067953560, 
1067960280, 1067966220, 1067975340, 1067980560, 1067984100, 1067986380, 
1067992380, 1067998200, 1068000780, 1068015300, 1068020460, 1068024420, 
1068026520, 1068032280, 1068038460, 1068051900, 1068060240, 1068065700, 
1068069720, 1068071520, 1068077460, 1068083220, 1068084060, 1068092760, 
1068105660, 1068110100, 1068111660, 1068117780, 1068123420, 1068124320, 
1068131760, 1068137820, 1068145140, 1068150600, 1068151140, 1068155280, 
1068156480, 1068161340, 1068162540, 1068168480, 1068178260, 1068190560, 
1068191160, 1068195840, 1068196620, 1068208620, 1068209940, 1068215760, 
1068223680, 1068235500, 1068236160, 1068241020, 1068241440, 1068254880, 
1068263940, 1068269940, 1068276240, 1068281580, 1068287220, 1068293700, 
1068295260, 1068301080, 1068309360, 1068315060, 1068326580, 1068326700, 
1068338580, 1068340560, 1068346380, 1068349680, 1068355500, 1068360960, 
1068373020, 1068378660, 1068380820, 1068384720, 1068387120, 1068395220, 
1068405900, 1068411480, 1068412260, 1068417480, 1068418440, 1068423720, 
1068426180, 1068429660, 1068431940, 1068435120, 1068441480, 1068451740, 
1068452040, 1068457680, 1068458640, 1068463620, 1068466380, 1068469680, 
1068472380, 1068480540, 1068486720, 1068490860, 1068496440, 1068498060, 
1068511800, 1068514740, 1068521100, 1068527280, 1068542400, 1068544260, 
1068548880, 1068558180, 1068566400, 1068572580, 1068575820, 1068581400, 
1068587280, 1068589500, 1068593820, 1068599700, 1068603120, 1068606840, 
1068612840, 1068622020, 1068627540, 1068629940, 1068639780, 1068666360, 
1068684720, 1068688980, 1068698640, 1068706800, 1068712440, 1068715500, 
1068724920, 1068729120, 1068730680, 1068743820, 1068757500, 1068760800, 
1068763440, 1068766800, 1068769920, 1068774300, 1068775740, 1068784260, 
1068801240, 1068810060, 1068816060, 1068829620, 1068836700, 1068842460, 
1068846540, 1068848280, 1068882540, 1068886860, 1068888540, 1068901080, 
1068915420, 1068921480, 1068927420, 1068927600, 1068932280, 1068933360, 
1068939720, 1068945420, 1068945780, 1068955800, 1068972540, 1068973440, 
1068978660, 1068985740, 1068991980, 1068991980, 1069001100, 1069012320, 
1069017840, 1069018380, 1069041480, 1069047480, 1069052580, 1069058700, 
1069064040, 1069071420, 1069077420, 1069103400, 1069109460, 1069115880, 
1069116600, 1067361120, 1067368740, 1067373660, 1067378340, 1067379480, 
1067393220, 1067400540, 1067413800, 1067419020, 1067419620, 1067431080, 
1067433420, 1067445960, 1067476140, 1067478960, 1067486460, 1067492220, 
1067493840, 1067504580, 1067519100, 1067531820, 1067549460, 1067549820, 
1067561280, 1067564460, 1067566980, 1067572020, 1067584740, 1067589600, 
1067596140, 1067601420, 1067605020, 1067617440, 1067623200, 1067629500, 
1067634480, 1067646180, 1067649780, 1067652060, 1067657880, 1067664000, 
1067669820, 1067676120, 1067682000, 1067686440, 1067692380, 1067714460, 
1067719740, 1067727120, 1067731260, 1067735520, 1067737320, 1067741340, 
1067743500, 1067749500, 1067765760, 1067775840, 1067777280, 1067781900, 
1067788800, 1067794920, 1067810520, 1067812680, 1067822340, 1067827080, 
1067829420, 1067835360, 1067884200, 1067895540, 1067898240, 1067907180, 
1067912580, 1067921100, 1067930640, 1067935800, 1067938920, 1067947200, 
1067947620, 1067953140, 1067960100, 1067966460, 1067975160, 1067977860, 
1067980440, 1067992320, 1067998200, 1067998380, 1068007020, 1068015540, 
1068020700, 1068024540, 1068032700, 1068038640, 1068051960, 1068060120, 
1068065520, 1068069540, 1068071400, 1068077280, 1068083340, 1068083700, 
1068086700, 1068105720, 1068110340, 1068111720, 1068123720, 1068124320, 
1068137700, 1068145080, 1068150240, 1068150960, 1068155160, 1068156360, 
1068168360, 1068169320, 1068178320, 1068191160, 1068195960, 1068196680, 
1068208800, 1068209760, 1068223440, 1068235920, 1068240840, 1068241500, 
1068246780, 1068253380, 1068255000, 1068264000, 1068270000, 1068276240, 
1068281580, 1068281580, 1068287580, 1068293640, 1068295320, 1068301440, 
1068309240, 1068326400, 1068326640, 1068332520, 1068338400, 1068340380, 
1068344640, 1068346560, 1068349740, 1068355800, 1068361080, 1068366600, 
1068367200, 1068373200, 1068378720, 1068380760, 1068384780, 1068386880, 
1068395040, 1068400920, 1068405900, 1068411540, 1068412260, 1068417480, 
1068418260, 1068423540, 1068426060, 1068429480, 1068431940, 1068435420, 
1068441540, 1068451740, 1068452280, 1068457560, 1068458760, 1068463800, 
1068466500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    lc = structure(c(4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    1L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
    6L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 
    6L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
    5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
    5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
    7L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 
    5L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
    5L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
    5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
    7L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 
    3L), .Label = c("1", "A", "B", "Tagging", "0", "2", "3", 
    "N", "P", "Z"), class = "factor"), lon = c(-39.37, -38.517, 
    -38.464, -38.461, -38.322, -38.674, -38.957, -42.084, -41.999, 
    -42.035, -42.14, -39.32, -39.306, -39.301, -39.301, -39.302, 
    -39.234, -39.215, -39.16, -39.179, -39.375, -39.185, -39.187, 
    -39.154, -39.197, -39.149, -39.214, -39.186, -39.165, -39.182, 
    -39.185, -39.184, -39.192, -39.21, -39.183, -39.2, -39.202, 
    -39.093, -39.157, -39.268, -39.227, -39.284, -39.376, -39.437, 
    -39.455, -39.46, -39.463, -39.457, -39.429, -39.365, -39.453, 
    -39.466, -39.505, -39.493, -39.472, -39.522, -39.493, -39.477, 
    -39.444, -39.461, -39.465, -39.418, -39.377, -39.421, -39.477, 
    -39.365, -39.338, -39.248, -39.265, -39.265, -39.528, -39.256, 
    -39.222, -39.183, -39.198, -39.178, -39.177, -39.16, -39.142, 
    -39.162, -39.181, -39.188, -39.181, -39.118, -39.13, -39.132, 
    -39.085, -39.07, -39.037, -39.018, -39.003, -38.965, -38.904, 
    -38.866, -38.891, -38.848, -38.826, -38.811, -38.781, -38.826, 
    -38.814, -38.82, -38.795, -38.775, -38.715, -38.763, -38.74, 
    -38.701, -38.742, -38.722, -38.714, -38.744, -38.714, -38.68, 
    -38.891, -38.671, -38.662, -38.653, -38.589, -38.575, -38.541, 
    -38.534, -38.465, -38.44, -38.437, -38.417, -38.417, -38.411, 
    -38.443, -38.34, -38.328, -38.236, -38.22, -38.306, -38.231, 
    -38.207, -38.249, -38.259, -38.283, -38.272, -38.307, -38.312, 
    -38.324, -38.359, -38.356, -38.412, -38.493, -38.543, -38.6, 
    -38.589, -38.608, -38.658, -38.692, -38.736, -38.784, -38.806, 
    -38.81, -38.469, -38.816, -38.874, -38.926, -38.905, -38.869, 
    -38.912, -38.912, -38.95, -38.911, -38.953, -39.112, -38.945, 
    -38.93, -38.932, -38.946, -38.96, -38.945, -38.972, -38.808, 
    -38.993, -39.008, -39.018, -39.027, -39.005, -39.005, -39.006, 
    -38.986, -38.931, -38.942, -38.944, -38.963, -38.949, -38.981, 
    -39.001, -38.951, -38.974, -38.94, -38.925, -38.904, -38.883, 
    -38.814, -38.773, -38.757, -38.737, -38.723, -38.728, -38.707, 
    -38.699, -38.785, -38.708, -38.675, -38.684, -38.648, -38.682, 
    -38.694, -38.763, -38.743, -38.744, -38.789, -38.79, -38.798, 
    -38.775, -38.801, -38.763, -38.744, -38.678, -38.591, -38.628, 
    -38.52, -38.525, -38.492, -38.458, -38.456, -38.438, -38.507, 
    -38.357, -38.092, -38.277, -38.274, -38.21, -38.196, -38.18, 
    -38.146, -38.116, -38.015, -38.067, -38.023, -38.03, -38.006, 
    -38.027, -38.038, -38.065, -38.078, -38.137, -38.087, -38.06, 
    -38.116, -38.239, -38.341, -38.372, -38.112, -38.498, -38.518, 
    -38.683, -38.633, -38.638, -38.703, -38.78, -38.922, -38.926, 
    -38.963, -38.992, -38.992, -38.973, -38.999, -38.979, -39.059, 
    -39.019, -39.02, -39.003, -39, -38.969, -38.954, -38.91, 
    -38.916, -38.948, -38.983, -38.929, -38.904, -38.945, -39.305, 
    -38.854, -38.721, -38.812, -38.759, -38.684, -38.687, -38.681, 
    -38.689, -38.473, -38.436, -38.417, -38.322, -38.327, -38.249, 
    -38.227, -38.214, -38.232, -38.205, -38.149, -38.09, -38.083, 
    -38.097, -38.075, -37.912, -38.085, -37.948, -38.103, -38.081, 
    -38.12, -38.06, -38.069, -38.069, -38.142, -38.126, -38.18, 
    -38.14, -38.157, -38.133, -38.141, -38.077, -38.126, -38.127, 
    -38.126, -39.48, -39.461, -39.441, -39.418, -39.45, -39.346, 
    -39.392, -39.271, -39.252, -39.243, -39.283, -39.089, -39.161, 
    -39.078, -39.052, -39.022, -39.047, -38.989, -38.954, -38.886, 
    -38.814, -38.714, -38.69, -38.583, -38.53, -38.507, -38.434, 
    -38.437, -38.391, -38.364, -38.414, -38.385, -38.444, -38.424, 
    -38.513, -38.523, -38.557, -38.557, -38.574, -38.603, -38.653, 
    -38.683, -38.719, -38.705, -38.711, -38.758, -38.708, -38.596, 
    -38.721, -38.723, -38.742, -38.77, -38.807, -38.743, -38.799, 
    -38.832, -38.882, -38.887, -38.92, -38.973, -39.038, -39.194, 
    -39.212, -39.296, -39.347, -39.382, -39.335, -39.675, -39.654, 
    -39.699, -39.747, -39.773, -39.794, -39.853, -39.863, -39.901, 
    -39.898, -39.899, -39.871, -39.86, -39.952, -39.914, -39.881, 
    -39.922, -39.996, -40.039, -40.044, -40.106, -40.186, -40.175, 
    -40.202, -40.258, -40.296, -40.434, -40.481, -40.485, -40.478, 
    -40.49, -40.485, -40.496, -40.483, -40.478, -40.499, -40.511, 
    -40.511, -40.624, -40.678, -40.726, -40.783, -40.76, -40.762, 
    -40.748, -40.751, -40.765, -40.764, -40.745, -40.662, -40.692, 
    -40.684, -40.784, -40.819, -41.012, -41.188, -41.251, -41.246, 
    -41.287, -41.386, -41.385, -41.441, -41.443, -41.397, -41.385, 
    -41.392, -41.339, -41.344, -41.329, -41.303, -41.343, -41.17, 
    -41.163, -41.14, -41.149, -41.162, -41.192, -41.185, -41.2, 
    -41.186, -41.268, -41.213, -41.214, -41.263, -41.243, -41.197, 
    -41.195, -41.23, -41.245, -41.205, -41.226, -41.259, -41.247, 
    -41.221, -41.228, -41.229, -41.216, -41.138, -41.136, -41.123, 
    -41.113, -41.156, -41.176, -41.148, -41.139, -41.138, -41.078
    ), lat = c(-18.48, -18.253, -18.302, -18.425, -18.512, -19.824, 
    -19.511, -24.071, -24.114, -24.152, -24.38, -18.46, -18.454, 
    -18.458, -18.475, -18.465, -18.433, -18.443, -18.414, -18.356, 
    -18.324, -18.34, -18.363, -18.318, -18.345, -18.315, -18.33, 
    -18.369, -18.366, -18.371, -18.386, -18.392, -18.393, -18.369, 
    -18.367, -18.37, -18.331, -18.36, -18.357, -18.352, -18.315, 
    -18.334, -18.382, -18.41, -18.43, -18.439, -18.442, -18.443, 
    -18.446, -18.458, -18.463, -18.473, -18.461, -18.523, -18.531, 
    -18.564, -18.553, -18.557, -18.567, -18.598, -18.597, -18.575, 
    -18.56, -18.546, -18.652, -18.533, -18.49, -18.492, -18.453, 
    -18.448, -18.328, -18.387, -18.351, -18.309, -18.285, -18.22, 
    -18.179, -18.159, -18.123, -18.096, -18.061, -18.041, -18.021, 
    -18.042, -18.008, -18.008, -18.026, -18.029, -18.039, -18.045, 
    -18.074, -18.064, -18.075, -18.097, -18.114, -18.103, -18.114, 
    -18.107, -18.059, -18.059, -18.046, -18.057, -18.024, -18.005, 
    -18.005, -18, -18.005, -17.899, -18.011, -18.017, -18.024, 
    -18.056, -18.051, -18.06, -18.186, -18.064, -18.064, -18.05, 
    -18.017, -17.996, -17.985, -17.97, -17.952, -17.94, -17.949, 
    -17.975, -17.955, -17.923, -17.889, -17.798, -17.747, -17.706, 
    -17.669, -17.675, -17.641, -17.556, -17.481, -17.399, -17.359, 
    -17.337, -17.275, -17.295, -17.265, -17.222, -17.218, -17.241, 
    -17.291, -17.301, -17.281, -17.23, -17.204, -17.17, -17.148, 
    -17.15, -17.057, -17.024, -17.009, -16.852, -16.908, -16.969, 
    -16.984, -16.958, -16.96, -16.957, -16.896, -16.935, -16.928, 
    -16.942, -16.852, -16.924, -16.898, -16.895, -16.841, -16.832, 
    -16.843, -16.763, -16.741, -16.778, -16.734, -16.69, -16.698, 
    -16.69, -16.647, -16.654, -16.606, -16.551, -16.5, -16.488, 
    -16.463, -16.472, -16.475, -16.449, -16.455, -16.467, -16.433, 
    -16.414, -16.387, -16.378, -16.324, -16.268, -16.231, -16.205, 
    -16.248, -16.188, -16.188, -16.161, -16.129, -16.104, -16.052, 
    -16.008, -15.991, -15.951, -15.943, -15.931, -15.928, -15.919, 
    -15.884, -15.903, -15.882, -15.966, -15.884, -15.916, -15.906, 
    -15.907, -15.872, -15.864, -15.889, -15.877, -15.917, -15.945, 
    -15.959, -15.976, -15.969, -15.98, -16.027, -15.994, -15.983, 
    -16.001, -15.995, -16.151, -16.004, -16.014, -15.995, -16.004, 
    -16.005, -15.985, -15.979, -16.06, -16.074, -16.105, -16.127, 
    -16.219, -16.223, -16.227, -16.331, -16.32, -16.351, -16.357, 
    -16.019, -16.397, -16.415, -16.28, -16.469, -16.479, -16.499, 
    -16.539, -16.617, -16.649, -16.631, -16.732, -16.865, -16.9, 
    -16.927, -17.013, -17.035, -17.077, -17.103, -17.129, -17.154, 
    -17.164, -17.311, -17.456, -17.494, -17.525, -17.6, -17.581, 
    -17.627, -17.668, -17.609, -17.819, -17.886, -17.845, -17.892, 
    -17.891, -17.869, -17.899, -17.913, -17.936, -17.931, -17.922, 
    -18.05, -18.1, -18.12, -18.122, -18.125, -18.132, -18.137, 
    -18.12, -18.173, -18.183, -18.218, -18.273, -18.307, -18.274, 
    -18.323, -18.291, -18.294, -18.34, -18.345, -18.354, -18.352, 
    -18.517, -18.539, -18.559, -18.572, -18.608, -18.626, -18.661, 
    -18.788, -18.841, -18.874, -18.872, -18.6, -18.561, -18.533, 
    -18.545, -18.577, -18.549, -18.469, -18.377, -18.372, -18.368, 
    -18.253, -18.28, -18.21, -18.116, -18.113, -18.132, -18.103, 
    -18.156, -18.096, -18.134, -18.203, -18.253, -18.246, -18.301, 
    -18.318, -18.328, -18.36, -18.427, -18.493, -18.595, -18.66, 
    -18.76, -18.889, -18.944, -18.957, -18.983, -19.116, -19.139, 
    -19.151, -19.204, -19.263, -19.307, -19.359, -19.408, -19.447, 
    -19.521, -19.543, -19.461, -19.491, -19.486, -19.462, -19.433, 
    -19.481, -19.488, -19.462, -19.473, -19.376, -19.383, -19.354, 
    -19.383, -19.442, -19.444, -19.453, -19.448, -19.475, -19.489, 
    -19.5, -19.687, -19.746, -19.772, -19.843, -19.865, -19.844, 
    -19.893, -19.935, -19.953, -20.034, -20.036, -20.102, -20.185, 
    -20.23, -20.327, -20.364, -20.372, -20.476, -20.528, -20.528, 
    -20.585, -20.645, -20.693, -20.716, -20.805, -20.821, -20.872, 
    -20.892, -20.922, -20.956, -20.984, -20.992, -21.044, -21.042, 
    -21.071, -21.239, -21.29, -21.315, -21.406, -21.399, -21.554, 
    -21.654, -21.73, -21.746, -21.785, -21.799, -21.882, -21.894, 
    -21.972, -22.096, -22.108, -22.122, -22.203, -22.19, -22.26, 
    -22.451, -22.472, -22.463, -22.448, -22.502, -22.495, -22.525, 
    -22.501, -22.519, -22.561, -22.563, -22.591, -22.626, -22.629, 
    -22.599, -22.589, -22.651, -22.649, -22.749, -22.82, -22.832, 
    -22.814, -22.793, -22.773, -22.739, -22.668, -22.637, -22.637, 
    -22.635, -22.677, -22.679, -22.693, -22.67, -22.597, -22.548, 
    -22.498, -22.459, -22.472, -22.447, -22.434, -22.431, -22.396, 
    -22.414, -22.397, -22.363, -22.33, -22.315, -22.315, -22.299, 
    -22.301, -22.296, -22.313)), row.names = c(NA, 506L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What did you try? Please post attempted code and desired result using sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, we can calculate the amount of time in days between each sampling:

```
gap_days<-vector() #Create an empty vector we will fill in later
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){ #Iterate of each row in your dataframe
  if (i==1){ 
    gap_days<-c(gap_days,NA) #For the first observation there is no gap
  } else if (df$id[i] != df$id[i-1]){ 
    gap_days<-c(gap_days,NA) #For the first observation of a new ID there is no gap
  } else {
    gap_days<-c(gap_days,difftime(df$date[i],df$date[i-1], units = "days")[[1]]) #Calculate the time between observations in days
  }
}

df<-cbind(df,gap_days) #Bind our new column onto your data
Over1Day<-subset(df, gap_days > 1) #Save a dataframe of those observations of more than 1 day
Over1Day #print that df to the screen
      id                date lc     lon     lat gap_days
20162.03 2003-10-21 12:19:00  1 -38.517 -18.253 1.906944
20162.03 2003-10-23 10:33:00  B -38.674 -19.824 1.654861
20162.03 2003-11-02 08:14:00  B -42.084 -24.071 9.598611
```

I am not sure what you mean by needing to split the tracks into 2 or more sub-tracks for the same id, with some individuals will have more then one burst, but I hope this gets you started.